# An API incompatibility was encountered and java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when using jmeter maven-analysis plugin

Tags: jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am running my meter test with jmeter-maven plugin and jmeter-maven-analysis plugin. tests are executed successfully but analysis report using the later plugin gives me the below error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin:1.0.6:analyze (jmeter) on project Jmeter_Maven: Execution jmeter of goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin:1.0.6:analyze failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin:1.0.6:analyze: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin:1.0.6
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/com/lazerycode/jmeter/jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin/1.0.6/jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin-1.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/org/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.15/jfreechart-1.0.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/org/jfree/jcommon/1.0.17/jcommon-1.0.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.04/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.5/itext-2.1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk14/138/bcmail-jdk14-138.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/138/bcprov-jdk14-138.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/charts4j/charts4j/1.3/charts4j-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.20/freemarker-2.3.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/home/bhanu_prakash/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/guava-14.0.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.'
```

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://Maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://Maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://Maven.apache.org/xsd/Maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.prakash.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>Jmeter_Maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>




<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>

                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFilesDirectories>
                                <testFilesDirectory>Assignment_flows</testFilesDirectory>
                                <testFilesDirectory>try</testFilesDirectory>
                            </testFilesDirectories>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
                      <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_report</artifactId>
                      <version>2.7</version>
                   </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                    <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-extras-libs</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.3</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                    <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-standard</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.3</version>
                  </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>analyze</goal>

                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                             <source>${project.build.directory}/target/jmeter/report/*.jtl</source>
                             <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/target/jmeter/report</targetDirectory>
                             <processAllFilesFound>true</processAllFilesFound>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.22</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.17</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>'
```

Comment: You are using an ancient version of the plugin, try with 1.10.0, or 1.10.1

Comment: Thanks but, The recent plugin has transient dependency issues on extras plugins of jmeter and doesn't compile my scripts.

Comment: The latest version of the jmeter-maven-plugin doesn't have transient dependency issues.  There are transient dependency issues with things that use JMeter 2.13 libraries that are in maven if they haven't put in a hack to work around the issues (the jmeter-maven-plugin has put in this hack).  jmeter-plugins suffers from this problem, so if you try to use jmeter-plugins with the jmeter-maven-plugin you will have issues.  That being said version 1.4.1 of the jmeter-maven-plugin doesn't support adding additional libraries so using the old version is not helping you.

Answer (score 0):

The version 1.4.1 is largely outdated, up to date version is 2.8.3 which eases the process of using 3rd party plugins through **jmeterExtensions** tag:

```
    <jmeterExtensions>
         <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.6</artifact>
     </jmeterExtensions>
```

This blog details the whole process using last version 2.8.3 of [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin):

- [Shift left your performance tests with JMeter and Maven](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/shift-left-performance-tests-jmeter-maven/)

Since the plugin now generates [Apache JMeter HTML report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), you don't need analysis plugin anymore.